# Getting "Cannot connect to the Docker daemon" error when creating new app from git repo in fabric8

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, fabric8, openshift-enterprise

I setup fabric8 on openshift origin 3.3, fabric8 version is "version 0.4.121". Wherever I  try to create new app from git repo in fabric8 it gives in this error:

```
[firstapp-testapp] Running shell script Executing shell script inside container [maven] of pod [kubernetes-085de53dd4cb4cfe990a727e68371b63-148fdbb6eea48] Executing command: sh -c echo $$ > '/home/jenkins/workspace/firstapp-testapp@tmp/durable-0d2c8f03/pid'; jsc=durable-f46e5a369ce24d99986ef5171a328446; JENKINS_SERVER_COOKIE=$jsc '/home/jenkins/workspace/firstapp-testapp@tmp/durable-0d2c8f03/script.sh'
> '/home/jenkins/workspace/firstapp-testapp@tmp/durable-0d2c8f03/jenkins-log.txt' 2>&1; echo $? > '/home/jenkins/workspace/firstapp-testapp@tmp/durable-0d2c8f03/jenkins-result.txt' [?1034hsh-4.2# cd /home/jenkins/workspace/firstapp-testapp sh-4.2# sh
-c echo $$ > '/home/jenkins/workspace/firstapp-testapp@tmp/durable-0d2  c8f03/pid'; jsc=durable-f46e5a369ce24d99986ef5171a328446; JENKINS_SERVER_COOKIE=  $jsc '/home/jenkins/workspace/firstapp-testapp@tmp/durable-0d2c8f03/script.sh'
>   '/home/jenkins/workspace/firstapp-testapp@tmp/durable-0d2c8f03/jenkins-log.txt' 2 
>&1; echo $? > '/home/jenkins/workspace/firstapp-testapp@tmp/durable-0d2c8f03/jen  kins-result.txt' 
+ docker tag accenture/firstapp-testapp:1.0.4 172.30.158.59:80/accenture/firstapp-testapp:1.0.4 Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host? sh-4.2# exit exit script returned exit code 1
```

Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 0):

Error is happening because of internal OpenShift problems. 
Please make sure that your OpenShift instance is properly installed.

To do that you can deploy one of the sample applications from catalog. 
To fix this problem manually you can execute following statement on OpenShift machines

```
service docker restart
```

Comment: thanks for the response, OpenShift is running fine and I have tested several apps but the issue is when I do that from fabric8 console. Docker is running fine on openshift. any help on this fabric8 issue?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to invoke `docker` from within a container?  You would need to change SCC to do that, though I do no recommend it.  There is likely a better way to accomplish the same thing.